# How can I access a field of a local-inner class from another method?

Tags: java

Consider the field `bar` of the local-inner class `MyValue`:

```
public class C {

public static void main(String x[]) {

    class MyValue implements IValue {
    String bar = "bar";
    public String  getValue() {
        return "my value";
    } 
    }
    MyValue myValue = new MyValue();

    D d = new D();
    d.accessBar(myValue);
}
}
```

which implements the `IValue` interface:

```
interface IValue {
public String getValue();
}
```

How can I access the field `bar` from another function (outside of `main`), let's say in class `D`:

```
class D {
public void accessBar(IValue value) {
    String info = value.getValue() + value.bar;
}   
}
```

Comment: can you put attributes in outside class?

Comment: *Why* can't you change the design of the code?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access the pass key of a ship and you only have the `IShip` interface, then `IShip` should have a `getPassKey()` method, basically. Even if you could cast to `ShipAddress` within the method, you *shouldn't* do so - you should make the parameter type for the `calculatedInfo` method suitable for all the operations the method requires.

You *could* access it via reflection, but that would be horribly brittle and I'd *strongly* recommend that you don't do that.

Comment: I don't have any restriction regarding interface I can create any method class or interface.also I ma not getting your point to access it via reflection,could you please edit answer with one or two line of code, so this could be more clear and understandable.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians: No, I'm not going to give an example of using reflection, because it's a horrible hacky way of doing it - if you don't already know about reflection, I don't want to give you *any* encouragement to do so. Add a `getPassKey()` method to the interface, implement it in your class, then call it in your method.